# Is it possible to have an element in a hidden block visible?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am taking over a web site and for a responsive site, I want to hide the class "**Hide**" and have class "**Visible**" visible. Is this possible? (I know I should rewrite this.... but time....)

(this is just an example, simplification of actual code)

```
 <div class="Hide">
       This will be hidden
       <span class="Visible>I want to be able to show this</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: If a parent is hidden, the children will be hidden as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it because it seems to work.

In this snippet the parent is given visibility: hidden, and the text that is in the div is not visible but the child is given visibility: visible and it is visible.

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden">This should be invisible
  <div class="visible">This should be visible</div>
  <div>This should be invisible</div>
</div>
```